# About Independency of Events

Tags: probability, independence

Is it necessary that whenever we have $\text{P(A)}\cdot \text{P(B)}=\text{P(A}\cap\text{B)}$, the events $\text{A}$ and $\text{B}$ are independent? If so, why is it a necessary condition?

Comment: This is the definition on independence.

Comment: That is my understanding of it. It goes back to cardinality of sets, if the intersection of sets A and B is the null set, they have nothing in common, hence they are independent. I hope that helps.

Comment: @Jabernet Disjoint is not the same as independent.

Comment: No, @Jabernet.  That is for *mutual exclusion* (or disjoint sets/events).  Independence is that the measure of the event $A$ is independent of whether $B$ happens or not.  If the intersection of the events has zero probability measure, then that is not the case (unless at least one of the events has no probability measure at all).

Answer (score 1):

Two events are considered independent, if knowledge of one event's occurrence (or not) does not affect the measure of probability of the other event.

That is to say, if the conditional probability of event A when event B happens equals the conditional probability of event A when event B does not happen, and both equal the unconditional probability of event A, then event A is independent of event B (and vice versa).

$$A\perp B \iff \Big(\mathsf P(A) = \mathsf P(A\mid B) = \mathsf P(A\mid B^\complement)\Big)$$

As a consequence of this, the probability of the conjunction of independent events is equal to the product of the probability of both events.   (Also known as the joint probability of the events).

$$\begin{align}
\mathsf P(A\cap B) & = \mathsf P(A\mid B)\,\mathsf P(B) \\[1ex] & \mathop{=}^\text{ind} \mathsf P(A)\,\mathsf P(B)\end{align}$$

That is all.